# Dynamically filter Series in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

I have an excel sheet in which the chart is dynamically generated each time it runs based on a data table within the sheet. However, due the Excel Series 255 limitation, the chart stopped generating.

Is there a way I can define a subset of Series so the chart can dynamically pull its related data from the table?

For example if I have:

```
   Product    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4 
   Apples     1   2   3   4  
   Bananas    3   4   5   6  
   Oranges    4   5   6   7 
   Strawberries 1  2  3   5
```

Within excel, how can I define only Apples, Oranges and Strawberries for the line chart so it will display its related Q-values?

TIA

Comment: How are you generating the chart now?  And why does the 255 limitation come into play?

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld for responding.It is configured to generate dynamically by selecting Product and Q values from the table. There are over 255 Rows so when Product is the series, the Excell throws a 255 limit series error. So wondering if there is a way to specify a list of products.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a simple filter.  For example, here is your data plotted originally.

[image: Original Data]

And here is the data after having

- applied a filter (Data Ribbon / Sort & Filter Tab / Filter)
- Select the table area
- execute `GoTo Special / Visible Cells Only`
- Insert a new graph

If this is something that needs to be done frequently, you could write a VBA macro to better automate the process.

[image: Filtered Data]

If you change a value in a visible series, the chart will change.  But if you change the filter, you will need to go through the process again.